# rich text with non editable content, angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textangular

I use directive [textAngular](http://textangular.com/) to format my email notification text and stuck for while with task when I need to add non editable html inside rich text. I added my custom directive over textAngular directive. With help my custom directive I  replace special characters in the string to html span tags with param `contenteditable='false'`, but this param doesn't work and content still editable.

In this case I have two questions:

1. How can I setup non-editable html inside content textAngular directive?
2. How can I concat my variable to the string to desire place (currently it always concats to the end of the string)

I appreciate any help.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tCc1ZC7GG53BBC30ofMS?p=preview) with my problem

My custom directive:

```
app.directive('removeMarkers', function () {

return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

       element.bind('click', function (e) {
                var target = e.target;
                var parent = target.parentElement;
                if (parent.classList.contains('label-danger')){
                    parent.remove()
                }
            });

        function changeView(modelValue){
            modelValue= modelValue
                .replace(/\{{/g, "<span class='label label-danger' contenteditable='false' style='padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 14px;'>")
                .replace(/\}}/g, "<span contenteditable='false' class='remove-tag fa fa-times'></span></span>&nbsp;");
            ngModel.$modelValue= modelValue;

            console.log(ngModel)
            return modelValue;
        }
        ngModel.$formatters.push(changeView);
        }
    }
});
```

Html

```
  <select class="form-control pull-right"
                style="max-width: 250px"
                ng-options="label.name as label.label for label in variables"
                ng-change="selectedEmailVariables(variable)"
                ng-model="variable">
            <option value="">template variables</option>
   </select>

  <div text-angular remove-markers name="email" ng-model="data.notifiation"></div>
```

Comment: It seems the developers are very reluctant to add this feature. Apparently a good alternative is ckeditor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) You can't [simply use `contenteditable='false'`](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/issues/230) attribute on your elements, since [`textAngular`strips it. To enable it](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/issues/143) in the past we had to download `textAngular-sanitize.min.js` and edit the array of allowed attributes. This starts with `J=f("abbr,align,`, you have to simply add `contenteditable` to this comma separated list.

2) To insert the template to the cursor position you can [use `wrapSelection` method within editor scope](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/issues/636), something like this could work:

```
$scope.selectedEmailVariables = function (item) {
    if (item !== null) {
          var editorScope = textAngularManager.retrieveEditor('editor1').scope;
          editorScope.displayElements.text[0].focus();
          editorScope.wrapSelection('insertHtml', 
          " <span class='label label-danger' contenteditable='false' style='color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 14px;'>" + item + "<span contenteditable='false' class='remove-tag fa fa-times'></span></span> ", true);
    }
};
```

Here is a [working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/A36fkuyxj9Dc7dTGrcln?p=preview).

P.S.: [`textAngular`](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular) seems to be a good editor, but it lacks some of the functionality and personally, I don't like its documentation. You have to gather a lot of info through the issues on the github. Right now switched to the other alternative editors, but possibly will get back to it in the future.

Comment: @antonyboom glad it helped you. We had to move to [`CKEditor`](https://ckeditor.com/), since it has better font management from the box, also it has a lot of plugins (image uploading, toolbar dropdowns, etc), the documentation seems to be more clear to me (but this is only my opinion :)). The only problem here - is to find/implement a good directive wrapper to use it.